# Pass vbscript variables to a JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, variables, vbscript

I have a vbscript that I use in Illustrator.  In order to save my file as a TIFF I need to use JavaScript.  With complete paths the JS script section works fine but when I try to change them to variables('NewState" and 'NewSection' via user input), it's a no go.  Nubie to JS so how to insert those variables?

Here's is my latest attempt (FYI - in Illustrator, to use JS inside VBS one must execute it as a String as shown below).

```
    Set App = CreateObject("Illustrator.Application")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")        
    Dim SourceFolder, DestFolder, NewState, NewSection
    Call GetNewInputs()
    Sub GetNewInputs()

        NewState = UCase(InputBox("Current STATE or REGION to be processed.", _
        "STATE or REGION", "SOCAL"))

        NewSection = ("Section_" & InputBox("INPUT SECTION NUMBER: Section_YY", _
        "Input Section", "32"))

        Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder("S:\" & NewState & "\" & NewSection & "\Road DXFs")
        DestFolder = "S:\" & NewState & "\" & NewSection & "\Light TIFFs\"

    End Sub       

   App.DoJavaScript("function test(){var doc = app.activeDocument;var destFile = new File(""/s/" + <%=NewState%> + "/" + <%=NewSection%> + "/Light TIFFs/SOCAL_CN68_resx.tif"");var type = ExportType.TIFF;var opts = new ExportOptionsTIFF();opts.imageColorSpace=ImageColorSpace.GrayScale;opts.resolution=72;opts.antiAliasing=AntiAliasingMethod.ARTOPTIMIZED;opts.IZWCompression=false;opts.saveMultipleArtboards=true;opts.artboardRange=""1"";doc.exportFile(destFile, type, opts);}test();")  

    MyDoc.Close(2)
```

Comment: Try changing the `<%=xxx%>` to `xxx` .

Comment: Is the JS in a <script> tag in the HTML of the page or a separate file? Is it in a JS file and being included with an HTML tag or is it with an <!--#include-->? It would help to have the JS in context.

Comment: THx for the suggestion, when just using 'xxx' I get an "Error  "Expected ')' ".  Is that not a syntax error?  Also, this ins not in any HTML or web page but a separate file.

Comment: Went back to the original method of '& xxx &' and this time it worked so I must have had some syntax (blank space?), out-a-whack.  All is good now.